# Different DataFrames in one Notebook--How to call them and interact with them?

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook

My level: Beginner. So I created different DataFrames in one Jupyter notebook using the .copy() method as I followed an on-line tutorial. I loaded the csv file and created the first df, then played with the df to subset the data (change columns, changing case on header), created df2, kept applying several more methods, and finally a new df (df3).

When I run the following method at the bottom of the notebook:
****variables = vars()
%who_ls DataFrame
Output:
['df3']
**

I scroll up the notebook and I still see the cells for df, df2, and the methods applied. If I run df.head or any other method with reference to df and df2 I get
"NameError: name 'ndf' is not defined"

What's going on? I thought the different df's were still "there" (terminology?) and you could call them.

Thanks,
M

I am working with the last df generated and was trying to call the previous dfs generated in the notebook but they don't seem to respond.

Comment: Are you sure your kernel didn't just time out?  Did you reopen the session? You cannot do that or you lose the namespace. You can pickle dataframes though or save as `.tsv`/`.csv` and read back in.  .... You need to show a minimal reproducible example in a code block. For example, you talk about `df` and `df2` and `df3` and then cannot figure out why you get `"NameError: name 'ndf' is not defined"`? If you only have `df` and `df2` and `df3`, then of course `ndf` isn't going to work. That's probably not the case but you can see why we cannot decipher your post without more actual details.

Comment: Wayne, thanks for your help. While following a tutorial, I was taking notes, looking online, testing, correcting in the notebook, and so on. It did take me ~3 days, I open and closed the computer a couple of times. Just now I reopened the notebook still have the same problem. In my explanation I called the df 1, 2, 3 to simplify the narrative but really I named them df, ndf, and df3. So the error (depending on what df I call for) reads: NameError: name 'df' is not defined. Keeping a notebook open for too long and opening/closing your laptop messes up the terminal and therefore the notebook?

Comment: Yes, if your computer sleeps,hibernates, or shuts down then the local server that Jupyter runs in shuts down & you have to re-execute earlier code to remake the dataframes in the active namespace of the session.  (As a result a common design step for a good notebook is to often restart the kernel and verify it makes everything without error as expected.) You may want to use Github's gist to share a demo **toy** notebook? Referencing the dataframes as you describe in your original post or in the last comment should work well. It sounds though like you may be a little confused how Jupyter works.

Comment: <continued> You cannot just re-open the `.ipynb` file after the active session is gone. You have to re-execute the code to re-establish the active namespace associated with the notebook. You can redesign to avoid having to do that entirely but in cases where it isn't 'expensive' to remake the dataframes, just remaking them is easiest. If they are 'costly' to make, you can pickle or store them as tab-separated or comma-separated values & then read back in the pickled dataframe or `.tsv`/`.csv`, as I suggested earlier. You can do either automated in one notebook if with conditional `if`s.

Comment: Oh man lots to digest here. I wonder then what's the best way, since I am just starting everything takes time, looking for explanations, alternative ways to do things, plus going to work and so on. These are not "expensive" it's all just playing with methods but it make me wonder how do work in "sessions". I do know the basic Jupyter functions (i.e., add new cell on top or bottom, mark down, run) but seems like I lack the fundamentals of its own operation. This is the first time I read "demo toy", and the idea of storing each df as csv to call them later. Thanks again so much.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to understand how Jupyter works? Most of what I found relates to how to work a csv, deleting, filtering, subsets, changing headers but it seems like I am missing the understanding how Jupyter works rather than how to work file a file once it's open.

Comment: Not really anything concise that I can point you to. Do you know how to use Python in the console/interpreter? If so, then what about IPython? IPython builds on Python and then IPython notebooks were built on IPython. The IPython notebooks project developed into Jupyter when it acquired the ability to use kernels other than Python-based. Some of the things you are running into, you only learn by experience. I know it is written down somewhere in the documentation that it needs a running server that you trigger but what that means for how you typically use Jupyter probably isn't spelled out ...

Comment: <continued> Like some of it is covered in the running documentation for JupyterLab [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/running.html). Maybe Jake VanderPlas' [Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/) is a good place to start? Then after some time using Jupyter, you may want to look around for the concept of 'kernels' and 'namespaces'. Plus some things don't work well running in notebooks. Related, you may want to look at Joel Grus slides at ...

Comment: <continued> ['I don't like notebooks.'](https://conferences.oreilly.com/jupyter/jup-ny/public/schedule/detail/68282.html).  Hopefully you are clear on your active dataframes issue now? Or still not?

Comment: Oh man you have helped me a lot, I am in debt to you. I am interested in data science, just self learning and lots of references about Jupiter everywhere, that’s why I started there. I already research namespaces and I understand better it better. I will look now in that book. Biochemistry it’s my background so learning data science it’s a new language almost. I would like to send you a small Starbucks gift card as appreciation for your help, let me know if this is ok.

Comment: That's very nice but there's no need for sending me the kind thank you. I'm a Biochemist/Molecular Biologist, too, so I know what you mean. It's a bit outdated in many ways now, but [Practical Computing for Biologists by Steven Haddock and Casey Dunn](https://practicalcomputing.org/) was a very good book targeted for scientists that I was introduced to a lot of stuff using it a decade ago. Maybe your library has it? They share cheatsheets for the appendices there at that site and they may help you get an idea of the scope of that book.

Comment: Great suggestion' I'll check it out. Now a senior scientist, I did a MSc, PhD, and postdoc. All within biochemistry/cell biology/molecular biology, so that's my domain expertise. Now that I want to learn data science is been a bit challenging but I am motivated. I do not need data science at work, so this is all on me, I want to be able to look for a job where I can be a scientist and do data analysis too. If you ever need career advice, or just to run any science stuff, if you want to geek out, you can find me at mar77x@gmail.com. Again I want to express my gratitude for helping a stranger.